# Why is my iPhone X camera still making shutter sounds even after I muted my phone?

Tags: iphone

I tried seeing YouTube videos on how to disable the sound but none of them are helpful. I tried to turn on my live mode on but it still makes a sound. Muting my phone is useless so I don’t know what to do.

Comment: I’m told that it is illegal to not have a shutter sound in some places, for example Japan (I’d put this as an answer, but I don’t have sources)

Comment: Yea but I don’t live in either of these places so I still don’t understand why the sound is there. None of my friends have this problem except me.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's illegal to mute the shutter sound in some country - Japan and Korea - as @Matthew Barclay stated in the comment.

Quote from [this website](https://www.engadget.com/2016-09-30-japans-noisy-iphone-problem.html):

> It was where I live: Japan. iPhones sold here (and in Korea) hold the dubious honor of being customized for their markets. We're not talking about extra mobile wallet functions, but a limitation -- a constraint. Ever since the iPhone 3GS arrived in Japan in 2008, taking a photo and even a screenshot (ugh) has been accompanied by a mandatory shutter noise -- one that iPhone users elsewhere probably turn off right away. Even switching to mute mode doesn't halt the awkward "passht" that was added to discourage covert photography.

> "This was done to prevent camera phones from being used in ways offensive to public morals. We continue to request handset manufacturers use the shutter sound"